# Reconizing a:hover with a <span>

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to turn a Wordpress nav menu item into a css button. Browser is recognizing css code for #navigation-menu ul > li.menu-item-3226 > a > span{...} so the normal button state looks fine but when I hover it doesn't recognize #navigation-menu ul > li.menu-item-3226 > a:hover > span{...} am I using incorrect CSS syntax or am I SOL? I can't change the generated html, so I am limited to modifying the CSS.

```
   CSS:
   #navigation-menu ul > li.menu-item-3226 > a > span{...}
   #navigation-menu ul > li.menu-item-3226 > a:hover span {... }
   #navigation-menu ul > li.menu-item-3226 > a:active span {...}

<div id="main-menu" class="pngfix">
<div id="dropdown-holder" class="container_24">
<div id="navigation-menu" class="navigation-menu">
<ul id="main-top-menu" class="sf-menu sf-js-enabled sf-arrows">
    <li id="menu-item-1021" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-86 current_page_item menu-item-1021">
    <li id="menu-item-3226" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3226">
        <a href="http://www.example.com/">
            <span>Order</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add the missing `>` to the hover style, it should do it.

```
#navigation-menu ul > li.menu-item-3226 > a:hover > span {... }
```

Comment: I started with that.  I took it out while debugging.

Comment: The reason why I took out the ">" was because when I inspected the page with Firebug it listed these in the style window:          #navigation-menu ul.sf-menu > li > a:hover span {...}      
    #navigation-menu ul > li.menu-item-3226 > a > span {...}

Comment: Should work, right?  I used your JSFIDDLE and added #navigation-menu ul.sf-menu > li > a:hover span { color:#0071BA; } above and the JSFIDDLE still worked.  For some reason it is not overwriting #navigation-menu ul.sf-menu > li > a:hover span { color:#0071BA; } on my page.  Looking at my code again for errors....

Comment: You might have answered your own question. `#navigation-menu ul.sf-menu > li > a:hover span` is more explicit than `#navigation-menu ul > li > a:hover span`

Comment: I had an open comment. Didn't see cuz it was in Wordpress editor and there are no color assistance that I am used to. F me.  Thanks.

Comment: @gimme10 OK, sounds like all good now, I recommend you a plugin called [WP Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-editor/) try it, makes life easier when comes to the built in theme editor.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is messed up (the first `<li>` doesn't close), but your CSS seems to work fine (see: http://jsfiddle.net/7w8eecov/).

Also, does the `<li>`s need to be found by class? Would `#navigation-menu ul li a:hover span {}` not work?

Comment: If I don't specify the class for the menu item, then it would effect all of the menu items.  I only want this to modify item-3226.

Comment: Ok, well you probably don't need all the `>` is your CSS. It looks like your styling is being overwritten elsewhere (http://jsfiddle.net/7w8eecov/1/). 1 idea could be to use `!important` after any rule to make sure it is taking precedence.